# Get All blob names from Storage account from Runbook

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I have a very simple script which absolutely works fine when run from remote powershell ISE (not using the RUNAS credentials from the Automation Runbook), but when we try to run it from Automation Runbook it returns 0 . Following is the code:-

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
$SubId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
try
{
    $servicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         
    Write-Verbose "Logging in to Azure..." -Verbose
    Connect-AzAccount -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId  -Tenant $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId -ServicePrincipal
    Write-Verbose "Setting Subscription......" -Verbose
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $SubId | Write-Verbose

}
catch {
        if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
        {
            $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
            throw $ErrorMessage
        } else{
            Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
            throw $_.Exception
        }
}

$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Name $StorageAccountName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

# Resource group name for the storage acccount
$ResourceGroup = "MYDEV01-RG"

# Storage account name
$StorageAccountName = "myDev01StrgName"


# Container name for analytics logs
$ContainerName = "`$logs"
$storageContext = $storageAccount.Context
$containers = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$container = Get-AzStorageContainer -Context $storageContext -Name $ContainerName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
        ForEach-Object { $containers.Add($_) } | Out-Null

Write-Output("> Container count: {0}" -f $containers.Count)
```

Not sure if we are missing something like permissions or some other thing because of with the Automation Account (Runbook) is not working, any help?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

After spending 24 hours on this one and staring and trying everything, it turned out that the ABOVE SCRIPT is correct and nothing is wrong in it but the STORAGE ACCOUNT's FIREWALL and NETWORK Setting were set to SELECTED NETWORK (You can either add the network IP addresses which you want to permit or select All Networks and that helped me resolve my issue). In NO WAYS I am suggesting SELECTING ALL NETWORKS but for testing we can and then add only the Selected networks and that should work.[image]